# Accordion control hides behind another control, how to bring it to front?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How can I get the accordion control which is defined in Grid row 0 go ON TOP of another panel which is defined in Grid row 1.....

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <toolkit:Accordion SelectionMode="ZeroOrOne" 
                           Grid.Row="0">
            <toolkit:AccordionItem Header='Pan Window'>

                <toolkit:AccordionItem.Content>
........
        </toolkit:AccordionItem.Content>

            </toolkit:AccordionItem>
        </toolkit:Accordion>


        <Grid  x:Name="LayoutRoot" Grid.Row="1">
...........
        </Grid>
```

The problem is that my Accordion control opens but is hidden behind the LayoutRoot grid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try setting the Canvas.ZIndex to be greater than the grid below it?

```
 <toolkit:Accordion SelectionMode="ZeroOrOne" Grid.Row="0" Canvas.ZIndex="1">
```

Comment: +1. That should do it.  It may feel strange attaching a Canvas attached property to something which isn't a child of a Canvas but the ZIndex is honored none-the-less.

Comment: Ok guys, what I did now was to put both controls on the same grid cell and set the zindex on both and it is doing what I was after......thanks for the help, appreciate it much...